# Parameters to AbstractTableModel functions exclude suffix "Index" for row and column

Tags: java, swing, indexing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

In the [java api for AbstractTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html), the parameters to `fireTableCellUpdated` are named `row` and `column`.  The parameters to `fireTableRowsDeleted`, `fireTableRowsInserted`, and `fireTableRowsUpdated` have parameters named `firstRow` and `lastRow`.  `getValueAt` and `setValueAt` (from [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html)), uses the names `rowIndex` and `columnIndex`.  Is there any meaning behind the lack of suffix "Index"?  Does it mean that I need to add one to `rowIndex` before passing `row` to 'fireTableCellUpdated' or `firstRow` to `fireTableRowsInserted`?

Comment: Short answer, no, it's just what who ever wrote the methods choose to use. It's fesiable that the API was expanded upon over a period of time, so the person who wrote the original (non-index suffixed) API was not the same person who wrote the index suffixed API. You could also get into a long winded argument over the use of the index suffix, me personally, I'd just like consistency :P

Answer (score 1):

I've seen conventions where the use of the "Index" suffix indicates that the first value starts with 0, and "Number" indicates possible values starting with 1.  No suffix may be ambiguous and require inspecting the code or looking at examples.

In the [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) tutorial, there is a sample implementation of AbstractTableModel.  In this example, they implement `setValueAt` and drop the "Index" suffix to the parameters compared to the method defined in [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html).  This is cosmetic, but they also pass those parameters to `fireTableCellUpdated` without adding 1 to the `row` and `column` parameters.  Therefore, I conclude that `fireTableCellUpdated`'s row and column variables are index based too.